# How do you reset the state of a Flutter widget with a PageStorageKey?

Tags: flutter, state

TLDR: How to force widget state to reinitialize

I have a List of nested ExpansionTiles with a PageStorageKey.  Each Tile has an attribute that can be selected/deselected.  Selected items are added to a list and returned back to the calling page. This functionality is working well.  The problem is that when I come back to the Selection page it is still holding the state of items previously selected.  After navigating (pop) back to the home page I would like for all the state data associated with the Selection page to be reset or deleted and reinitialized.

I added deactivate() and dispose() methods but it's still holding on to the state.  I also added a unique key but that didn't help.

[home page[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTb14.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var txtField = TextEditingController();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Home Page'),
          ),
          body: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Form(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: txtField,
                  onTap: () async {
                    final result = await Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                            OccupationSelection(),
                      ),
                    );
                    txtField.text = result.toString();
                  },
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.work),
                    labelText: 'Select an Occupation',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class OccupationSelection extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> selectedOccupation = List<String>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Select An Occupation'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: occupationDB.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => OccItem(
          context,
          occupationDB[index],
          (String item) {
            selectedOccupation.add(item);
          },
          (String item) {
            selectedOccupation.remove(item);
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Save'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop(selectedOccupation.join('+'));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


// Create the Widget for the row
class OccItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final Occupation entry;
  final Function addOccupation;
  final Function delOccupation;
  final context;

  OccItem(this.context, this.entry, this.addOccupation, this.delOccupation);

  @override
  OccItemState createState() => OccItemState();
}

class OccItemState extends State<OccItem> {
  final Color _iconColor = Colors.black;

  Widget _buildTiles(Occupation root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.grey[300],
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 20.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 20, right: 20),
          child: ListTile(
            //key: _key,
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                    root.occSelected
                        ? Icons.check_box
                        : Icons.check_box_outline_blank,
                    color: _iconColor),
                onPressed: () {
                  root.occSelected == false
                      ? widget.addOccupation('${root.occId}${root.occTitle}')
                      : widget.delOccupation('${root.occId}${root.occTitle}');
                  root.occSelected = !root.occSelected;
                  setState(() {});
                  Scaffold.of(widget.context)
                    ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
                    ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      content: root.occSelected
                          ? Text(
                              'Occupation Selected ${root.occTitle}',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                            )
                          : Text(
                              'Occupation Removed ${root.occTitle}',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                            ),
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
                    ));
                }),
            title: Text(root.occTitle),
          ),
        ),
      ); //Detail item
    }
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      child: Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 20, right: 20),
        child: ExpansionTile(
          key: PageStorageKey<Occupation>(root),
          title: Text(root.occTitle),
          children: root.children.map<Widget>(_buildTiles).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    ); //High level item
  }

  void deactivate() {
    super.deactivate();
  }

  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(widget.entry);
  }
}

class Occupation {
  final String occId;
  final String occTitle;
  bool occSelected;
  List<Occupation> children;

  Occupation(this.occId, this.occTitle, this.occSelected,
      [this.children = const <Occupation>[]]);
}

// Occupation Database
List<Occupation> occupationDB = <Occupation>[
  Occupation(
    '1.',
    'Business',
    false,
    <Occupation>[
      Occupation(
        '1.1.',
        'Management',
        false,
        <Occupation>[
          Occupation('1.1.1.', 'Accounting', false),
          Occupation('1.1.2.', 'Administration', false),
          Occupation('1.1.3.', 'Business Development', false),
          Occupation('1.1.4.', 'Finance | Financial Services | Securities', false),
          Occupation('1.1.5.', 'Human Resources', false),
        ],
      ),
      Occupation(
        '1.2.',
        'Construction | Architecture',
        false,
        <Occupation>[
          Occupation('1.2.1.', 'Commercial', false),
          Occupation('1.2.2.', 'Residential', false),
          Occupation('1.2.3.', 'Design', false),
          Occupation(
            '1.2.4.',
            'Trades',
            false,
            <Occupation>[
              Occupation('1.2.4.1.', 'Brickmason | Blockmason', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.2.', 'Carpenter', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.3.', 'Cement Mason | Concrete Finisher', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.4.', 'Construction', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.5.', 'Electrician', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.6.', 'Glazier', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.7.', 'HVAC', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.8.', 'Iron', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.9.', 'Painter', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.10.', 'Plumber', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.11.', 'Welder', false),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ), //Business
  Occupation(
    '2.',
    'Education',
    false,
    <Occupation>[
      Occupation('2.1.', 'Administration', false),
      Occupation('2.2.', 'Athletics', false),
      Occupation('2.3.', 'Curriculum Development', false),
      Occupation(
        '2.4.',
        'Teaching',
        false,
        <Occupation>[
          Occupation('2.4.1.', 'Pre-school', false),
          Occupation('2.4.2.', 'Elementary', false),
          Occupation('2.4.3.', 'Middle School', false),
          Occupation('2.4.4.', 'High School', false),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ), //Education
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the issue is that you are using a global variable for storing Occupation details. And every time you are using it directly.
Either you can create its copy when its used or you will have to reset the selection values. This solution is based on resetting the occSelected value.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var txtField = TextEditingController();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Home Page'),
          ),
          body: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Form(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: txtField,
                  onTap: () async {
                    for (Occupation occupation in occupationDB) {
                      occupation.resetAllValues();
                    }

                    final result = await Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                            OccupationSelection(),
                      ),
                    );
                    txtField.text = result.toString();
                  },
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.work),
                    labelText: 'Select an Occupation',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class OccupationSelection extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> selectedOccupation = List<String>();

  List<Occupation> occupationList = occupationDB;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Select An Occupation'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: occupationList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => OccItem(
          context,
          occupationList[index],
          (String item) {
            selectedOccupation.add(item);
          },
          (String item) {
            selectedOccupation.remove(item);
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Save'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop(selectedOccupation.join('+'));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Create the Widget for the row
class OccItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final Occupation entry;
  final Function addOccupation;
  final Function delOccupation;
  final context;

  OccItem(this.context, this.entry, this.addOccupation, this.delOccupation);

  @override
  OccItemState createState() => OccItemState();
}

class OccItemState extends State<OccItem> {
  final Color _iconColor = Colors.black;

  Widget _buildTiles(Occupation root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.grey[300],
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 20.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 20, right: 20),
          child: ListTile(
            //key: _key,
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                    root.occSelected
                        ? Icons.check_box
                        : Icons.check_box_outline_blank,
                    color: _iconColor),
                onPressed: () {
                  root.occSelected == false
                      ? widget.addOccupation('${root.occId}${root.occTitle}')
                      : widget.delOccupation('${root.occId}${root.occTitle}');
                  root.occSelected = !root.occSelected;
                  setState(() {});
                  Scaffold.of(widget.context)
                    ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
                    ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      content: root.occSelected
                          ? Text(
                              'Occupation Selected ${root.occTitle}',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                            )
                          : Text(
                              'Occupation Removed ${root.occTitle}',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                            ),
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
                    ));
                }),
            title: Text(root.occTitle),
          ),
        ),
      ); //Detail item
    }
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      child: Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 20, right: 20),
        child: ExpansionTile(
          key: PageStorageKey<Occupation>(root),
          title: Text(root.occTitle),
          children: root.children.map<Widget>(_buildTiles).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    ); //High level item
  }

  void deactivate() {
    super.deactivate();
  }

  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(widget.entry);
  }
}

class Occupation {
  final String occId;
  final String occTitle;
  bool occSelected;
  List<Occupation> children;

  Occupation(this.occId, this.occTitle, this.occSelected,
      [this.children = const <Occupation>[]]);

  resetAllValues() {
    print("This should reset");
    this.occSelected = false;
    for (Occupation child in children) {
      child.resetAllValues();
    }
  }
}

// Occupation Database
List<Occupation> occupationDB = <Occupation>[
  Occupation(
    '1.',
    'Business',
    false,
    <Occupation>[
      Occupation(
        '1.1.',
        'Management',
        false,
        <Occupation>[
          Occupation('1.1.1.', 'Accounting', false),
          Occupation('1.1.2.', 'Administration', false),
          Occupation('1.1.3.', 'Business Development', false),
          Occupation(
              '1.1.4.', 'Finance | Financial Services | Securities', false),
          Occupation('1.1.5.', 'Human Resources', false),
        ],
      ),
      Occupation(
        '1.2.',
        'Construction | Architecture',
        false,
        <Occupation>[
          Occupation('1.2.1.', 'Commercial', false),
          Occupation('1.2.2.', 'Residential', false),
          Occupation('1.2.3.', 'Design', false),
          Occupation(
            '1.2.4.',
            'Trades',
            false,
            <Occupation>[
              Occupation('1.2.4.1.', 'Brickmason | Blockmason', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.2.', 'Carpenter', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.3.', 'Cement Mason | Concrete Finisher', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.4.', 'Construction', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.5.', 'Electrician', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.6.', 'Glazier', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.7.', 'HVAC', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.8.', 'Iron', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.9.', 'Painter', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.10.', 'Plumber', false),
              Occupation('1.2.4.11.', 'Welder', false),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ), //Business
  Occupation(
    '2.',
    'Education',
    false,
    <Occupation>[
      Occupation('2.1.', 'Administration', false),
      Occupation('2.2.', 'Athletics', false),
      Occupation('2.3.', 'Curriculum Development', false),
      Occupation(
        '2.4.',
        'Teaching',
        false,
        <Occupation>[
          Occupation('2.4.1.', 'Pre-school', false),
          Occupation('2.4.2.', 'Elementary', false),
          Occupation('2.4.3.', 'Middle School', false),
          Occupation('2.4.4.', 'High School', false),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ), //Education
];
```